# Angular/Ionic RXJS update Observable array rather than appending

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, rxjs

This is a function for an ionic app that shows all the users close by you.. the issue is if a user changes their name or location it gets added as a new item in the array rather than updating the existing item... how is it possible for me to feed the update to the ionic2 ngFor loop ?

```
public outputUsersCloseToMe() : Observable<Array<displayAllUsers>> {

    let availableUsers = <Array<displayAllUsers>>[];

        this.firebaseInit().database().ref('users').child(key).child('profile').on('value', (userprofile) => {  
            if( userprofile.val() ) {
                availableUsers.push({ 
                    id: userprofile.val().id,                        
                    gender: userprofile.val().gender,
                    distance: distance.toFixed(2),
                    location: location,
                    firstName: userprofile.val().firstName,                        
                });        
            }
        }); 

    return Observable.from([availableUsers]).map(val => val); 
}
```

Comment: Well you are pushing a new item to the array, so this is expected behavior. Easy solution: clear the array before pushing new item in it...

Comment: Yeah thats the fallback plan but surely there is something a bit more elegant offered by RXJS

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map instead of an array.

```
let availableUsers = <Map<String,displayAllUsers>> new Map;
```

You update it by id

```
availableUsers.set(id, { 
  id: userprofile.val().id,                        
  gender: userprofile.val().gender,
  distance: distance.toFixed(2),
  location: location,
  firstName: userprofile.val().firstName,                        
});
```

You create an observable with just the `values` stored in the map

```
return Observable.from([availableUsers.values()]);
```

Comment: Thanks man, ive tried it out and it gives me the error .set is not a function

Comment: You need to use `new Map` instead of `{}`. Code updated

Comment: still not luck  Cannot find a differ supporting object 'null' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: It looks like Angular is not able to process an observable of iterators, it wants an observable of iterables (or arrays). Instead map's  `values` returns an iterator. Try `return Observable.from([[...availableUsers.values()]]);`

Comment: Actually `Observable.of([...availableUsers.values()]);` is the same and looks better

Comment: using Observable.of([...availableUsers.values()]); is complaining that its not an array type now :)